# Why useEffect doesn't set items from local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've started to learn web development recently and this is making my head hurt. I made a simple todo app where you can add an item with id and value to an array and delete the item from the array. Now I want whenever the site refreshes, I want the items to be there. I made a testing array and for some reason, when refreshed, it works but not with `data`.

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const testarr = [{id: 1, value: "a"}, {id: 2, value: "b"}];

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    console.log(data);
    // setItems(testarr);
    setItems(data);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
  }, [items]);
```

What I came up with:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    data.forEach(element => {
      setItems(oldarr => [...oldarr, element]);
    });
  }, [])
```

The problem is, if I keep refreshing the site fast enough, eventually the array will become empty again. I don't understand, when refreshed it logs `data` just fine but when I want to `setItems(data)` that doesn't work. Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is an asynchronous function, this implies that this code snippet below will always run with items as empty arrays before items receive data from "setItems(data)".

```
    useEffect(() => {
       window.localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
    }, [items]);
```

maybe, you can check if items isn't a empty array before store

```
    useEffect(() => {
       if (Array.isArray(items) && items.length > 0) {
           window.localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
       }
    }, [items]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try localStorage without window Object

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
  }, [items]);
```

Comment: I've tried it, no success.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The below `useEffect` runs every time `items` changes, but also on mount. And on mount `items` is equal to `[]`, that array given to `useState` in the beginning. That's why the `localStorage` is being set to `[]`.

```
useEffect(() => {
 window.localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
}, [items]);
```

## Solution

One way to solve this issue is to change your state definition as below, so when there is data in the `localStorage` you pick it:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(!localStorage.getItem("items") ? [] : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items")));
```

And at this point, you can remove those two `useEffect`s you have there for getting data from the `localStorage` and giving it to `setItems`.

Comment: When I try to log Items, only empty array gets printed. When I use useEffect it gets added to localstorage and on refresh I can only log the data out and not setItems(data)

Comment: Did you add items before doing that?

Comment: What about checking for `items.length` before setting `localStorage` in the `useEffect`?

Comment: @yousoumar yes, I've tried adding items.

Comment: Did only remove the two below useEffect I mentioned, and kept the first one?